# Header logo linking issue (WordPress)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I apologize in advance if this question has already been answered but I'm having the hardest time making my logo linkable here: http://testsite.brentthelendesign.com/. This is a WordPress "Skeleton" based site. Any help would be greatly appreciated! The code is below.

HTML

```
<header class="left full header-bg">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container-inside left">
            <div class="sixteen columns">
                <h1 class="logo abs"><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>"/></a></h1>
                <nav>
                    <?php st_navbar(); ?>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--container-->
 </header>
```

CSS

```
h1.logo {
left:50%;
margin-left:-80px;
float: none;
text-align: center;
}


h1.logo a {
background:url(images/logo.png) no-repeat;
width:181px;
height:127px;
display:block;
text-indent:-9999px;
float: none;
text-align: center;
cursor: pointer;
}


.header-bg {
height: 190px;
background: url(images/bg-header.png) repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>  using this css you can display your logo with your home url.


h1.logo {
    float: none;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -80px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10000;
}

h1.logo a img{
                display:block;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. Thanks so much...duh. I simply didn't define h1.logo img

Answer (score 0):

You're template is set up to use the `WP_HOME` value as the link, which is configurable in the Wordpress Admin under `Settings > General`. You can also override this value by explicitly setting the constant values in your `wp-config.php`:

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com');
```

You can also just edit the template file if you want to hardcode it (which is more efficient if it's never going to change), replace `<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>` with your desired URL.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. Iv'e tried your suggestions and the logo simply isn't clickable... Could this be something to do with it being a background image?

Comment: It's a background element on an anchor tag, so the `A` should be clickable. Can you use "Inspect Element" in chrome to make sure the DOM element is selectable?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try instead of setting your logo as a background image through css to put it here?

```
<h1 class="logo abs">
   <a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>"/>
     <image src="">  
   </a>
</h1>
```

Try this and tell me how it goes.

Comment: hmmm.....I tried this as well, and the image doesn't even show up until I set h1.logo a to h1.logo a {display:inline;} But the image still isn't linkable.